# pythonic style of nested path imports

Tags: python, linux, python-import

I have a project with multiple subdirectories like so:

```
/opt/exampleProject/src
├── __init__.py
├── dir1
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── file.py
│    └── file2.py
└── dir2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── file3.py
    └── file4.py
```

My main.py file lives here

```
/usr/bin/main.py
```

I wanted to know the cleanest way to import exampleProject to be used by main. The fileX.py files also import each other and there are a lot more then shown here. What I would like to be able to do is add this to my $PYTHONPATH so that the main.py can just import them. Is there anyway to do this ?

I have been thinking of adding them all individually with.

```
 sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

But I was hoping there was a nice way to do this.

Comment: you just need to `sys.path.append` the exampleProejct dir, and all of modules would be available. If you need to import then all, add the import statements to root package `__init__.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing with `sys.path` is strongly discouraged. [Instead create a package for `/opt/exampleProject` by creating a `setup.py`.](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject)

```
/opt/exampleProject
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── file.py
    │   └── file2.py
    └── dir2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── file3.py
        └── file4.py
```

afterwards install it using

```
pip install -e /opt/exampleProject
```

After doing that you can simply do

```
import example_project
```

in any other python script or package.

Comment: This would work nicely however i am building up this project to be installed via rpm and easy_install. Could this work in that kind of setup ?
like easy_install /opt/exampleProject/ ?

sorry i did not mention that in the original post i was trying to narrow down the question.

Comment: In that case the sources should simply not go into `/opt/sampleProject` but instead in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sampleProject`. `import sample_project` will then just work from anywhere.